# how to take sum of each ObjectList, DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

thanks for your time:

i am trying to get the sum of all Pets separeted by People:

models.py:

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person')
    birthday = models.DateField()
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user)


class Pets(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='peop')
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    tipo = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.pessoa, self.nome)
```

views.py

```
    q7 = People.objects.all()
    for p in q7:
        q8 = Pets.objects.filter(pessoa=p)
        l=[]
        for pet in q8:
            custa = pet.custo
            l.append(custa)
            custo_total2 = sum(l)
```

its returning me just the sum of the last People.Pets query
i guess i'm not understanding the logic

Comment: Apart from arakkal abu's answer, in your implementation, the scope of `custo_total2` is not correct. You should change it's indentation(remove four spaces before this).

Comment: i've tried it either it stills returns me the sum of the last q8 query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`Group By`** query as,

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Pets.objects.values('pessoa').annotate(sum=Sum('custo'))
```

Comment: i don't get it. should i assign this to a variable(query) and pass to the template and render like:
```

for q in query:
    q.sum

Comment: have you checked the result of `Pets.objects.values('pessoa').annotate(sum=Sum('custo'))` ? then you will understand

Comment: thak you so much sir, any tip to how to get pessoa value as People.user?

Comment: use **`pessoa__user`** instead of `pessoa`  to get the PK of AuthUser